# Undocumented Yahoo! Weather API?

Tags: yahoo-weather-api

According to the [Yahoo! Weather API documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/), a [WOEID](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html) must be provided to obtain weather information for a specific region. The WOEID can be obtained by using the [Yahoo! GeoPlanet](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/) service.

If I have a zip code, this is two API calls to obtain weather information.

Get the WOEID from a zip code: http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q(19146)?appid=...
Get the weather info using WOEID: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12765532

However, after some web crawling I found that you can do the exact same thing with one API call:

http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=19146

I couldn't find any documentation on this. Is it safe to use in a production application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the api documentation [says](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#params):

> Note: The old location parameter 'p' has been deprecated and will be removed in the future releases. Hence users are encouraged to migrate to the 'w' parameter which provides deep integration into Y! GeoPlanet. The old documentation is archived [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/archive.html).

so: using `p` doesn't seem to be the best idea for production code to me.